# Laravel - adding VerifyCsrfToken to controller getting ajax request

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, csrf, csrf-protection

I am creating a controller that receive an AJAX request and from Laravel documentation, i can send header with X-Csrf token 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token

On my Controller i have something like this :

```
 public function checkPromotion(Request $request)
{

    try {
        $this->middleware('VerifyCsrfToken');
    }
    catch (TokenMismatchException $e){
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Error Token Provided']);
    }


}
```

}

When i tried and sent a blank post request to this controller , the respond was blank .

Answer (score 2):

There are three issues here:

1. If you are going to add middleware in a controller, you must do so in the constructor.
2. Out of the box, you cannot handle middleware exceptions in a controller action. You'll need to [handle the exception](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/errors#the-exception-handler) in your `\App\Exceptions\Handler` class. The `handle` method of that class will receive the `TokenMismatchException` when token verification fails.
3. The string `'VerifyCsrfToken'` is not a valid way to reference your middleware.

Regarding #3, the `middleware` method takes the name of a [middleware group](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/middleware#middleware-groups), or the FQCN of a particular middleware.

The following should work:

```
$this->middleware(\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class)
```

(I'm assuming that you are using the default App namespace)

If you get a "Session store not set on request" exception, it's because cannot use CSRF middleware without the StartSession middleware.

Most likely what you really want is the web middleware:

```
$this->middleware('web')
```

This will include the CSRF middleware, the session start middleware, and a few others (see your http kernel for details).

If needed you can [exclude routes from CSRF verification](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/csrf#csrf-excluding-uris) by using the `$except` array in your `VerifyCsrfToken` class

Comment: I tried , still getting a blank respond 
try {
            $this->middleware(VerifyCsrfToken::class);
        }
        catch (TokenMismatchException $e){
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Error Token Provided']);
        }

Comment: @user2873860 Did you import VerifyCsrfToken?

Comment: it did not work , i tried both way  if (!$this->middleware(VerifyCsrfToken::class)){
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Error Token Provided']);
        }
        
         try {
            $this->middleware(VerifyCsrfToken::class);
        }
        catch (TokenMismatchException $e){
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Error Token Provided']);
        }

Comment: @user2873860 Just noticed that you are adding the middleware in the controller action, you have to do it in the constructor.

Comment: I tried adding in class construct , error showing RuntimeException in Request.php line 905:
Session store not set on request.
However i need to use it in one method not whole class , is there any way .

Comment: @user2873860 Updated my answer with additional details

Answer (score 1):

The `middleware` method on `Controller` is registering a middleware in an array on the controller. That middleware is not ran at that point.

When this method is called in a constructor the router/route collection will have access to the `getMiddleware` method after the Controller has been resolved to be able to build the middleware stack needed for the current route/action.

You may want to be dealing with this exception in your exception handler, `App\Exceptions\Handler`.

[Laravel 5.5 Docs - Errors - The Exception Handler - Render Method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/errors#render-method)

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof \Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Error Token Provided']);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain how i deal with App\Exceptions\Handler for this purpose ?

Comment: how is laravel by default when form is submitted to controller it verify it token , i need to make my controller to deal with ajax request as it's a form , need a token header

Comment: as mtinsley has pointed out about the `web` middleware group ... it provides sessions and the VerifyCsrfToken middleware ... all your routes in `routes/web.php` should already have the entire `web` middleware group applied by default

Answer (score 0):

```
protected function tokensMatch($request)
{
    // If request is an ajax request, then check to see if token matches token provider in
    // the header. This way, we can use CSRF protection in ajax requests also.
    $token = $request->ajax() ? $request->header('X-CSRF-Token') : $request->input('_token');

    return $request->session()->token() == $token;
}
```

Add this function inside VerifyCsrfToken.php